# Select count from one field

Tags: mysql, select, count, sql-like

I have a MySQL Query that looks like this...

```
SELECT `option_name` FROM `wp_9_options` WHERE option_name LIKE '%registered_domains_%' LIMIT 0 , 30
```

I also want to show a count of how many times the text '.com' appears in the 'option_value' field. The field contains various text and I'm looking for domains.

The domains could be various (.com, .net, .co.uk etc) but I'm trying to keep it simple by just looking for .com's

Thanks for any help provided.

Steve

No solutions yet but I do appreciate those that have tried.

Comment: Does it have to be where the option_name has registered domains in the field and option_value has a .com?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT option_name,    
    ROUND (   
    (
        LENGTH(option_value)
            - LENGTH( REPLACE ( option_value, ".com", "") ) 
        ) / LENGTH(".com")        
    ) AS dot_com_count    
FROM wp_9_options
WHERE option_name LIKE '%registered_domains_%'
LIMIT 0 , 30;
```

Comment: thanks for that sly! it's not quite right though because option_value contains various text and not just domain names. Also there could be more than one domain in each option_value which is the reason i'm trying to count them. I want to see how many domains each option_value contains.

Comment: Understood, I've updated my answer, give it a try and let me know if it doesn't work for you.  Also, I've updated my SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6098c/1/0

Comment: You're welcome.  Just be careful with the data, if you have Domains stored in uppercase, the query will need to be modified so that it is case-insensitive.

Answer (score -1):

SELECT option_name, COUNT(option_name) AS total FROM wp_9_options WHERE option_name LIKE '%.com' LIMIT 0 , 30